# 401 error searching Spotify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, spotify, http-status-code-401

I keep getting the following error no matter what i do:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=eminem 401 (Unauthorized)

I think i am getting the access token (see the code below) but for some reason it is not registering. The code for the methods are below and underneath that is the main page for the app where the methods are being used. Any help you can give is greatly appreciated!

**Spotify.js**

```
  export const Spotify = {
  **getAccessToken()** {
    if (accessToken) {
      return new Promise(
        resolve => resolve(accessToken)
      );
    } else {
      const accessTokenCheck = window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/);
      const expiresInCheck = window.location.href.match(/expires_in=([^&]*)/);

      if (accessTokenCheck && expiresInCheck) {
        accessToken = accessTokenCheck;
        const expiresIn = expiresInCheck;
        window.setTimeout(() => accessToken = '', expiresIn * 1000);
        window.history.pushState('Access Token', null, '/');
      } else {
        window.location = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + clientId + '&response_type=token&scope=playlist-modify-public&redirect_uri=' + redirectURI;
      }

      return new Promise(
        resolve => resolve(accessToken)
      );
    }
  },

  **search(term)** {
    return Spotify.getAccessToken().then( () => {
      return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=${term}`
      , {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      }).then(
        response => response.json()
      ).then(
        jsonResponse => {
          if (jsonResponse.tracks) {
            return jsonResponse.tracks.items.map(track => {
              return {
                id: track.id,
                name: track.name,
                artist: track.artists[0].name,
                album: track.album.name,
                uri: track.uri
              };
            });
          }

      }
      )
    })
  },

  **savePlaylist(playlistName,trackURIs)**{
        if(playlistName && trackURIs){
            const currentUserAccessToken = accessToken;
            const headers = {Authorization: window.location.href.match(/access_token=([^&]*)/)};
            const userID = null;
            fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',{headers: headers}).then(response => {
            if (response.ok){
            return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Request failed!');
            }, networkError => console.log(networkError.message)
            ).then(jsonResponse => {
                const userID = jsonResponse.id;
            });

            fetch('https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/{user_id}/playlists', {
            headers: headers,
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({id: '200'})
            }).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
            }
            throw new Error('Request failed!');
            }, networkError => console.log(networkError.message)
            ).then(jsonResponse => {
                const playlistID = jsonResponse.id;
            });




        }
        else{
        return playlistName && trackURIs;
        }
  }

  };

export default Spotify;
```

**App.js**

```
 search(term){

        Spotify.search(term).then(tracks=>{
            this.setState({
                tracks:tracks
            })
        });
    }


    //  {tracks: {items: {[rest of data]}}}


  render() {
    return (
    <div>

        <div className="App">
            <SearchBar onSearch={this.search}/>
            <div className="App-playlist">
                <SearchResults onAdd={this.addTrack} searchResults={this.state.search} />
                <Playlist onRemove={this.removeTrack} playlistName={this.state.playlistName} playlistTracks ={this.state.playlistTracks} onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName} onSave={this.savePlaylist} />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```